# Same Background for 2 Components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm not sure how to implement this with react-navigation.

I want to navigate between 2 components while keeping a static background image. So basically, the content would move over the single background image. How can I do this/is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a scrollView with paging enabled; this way you can keep a single static background photo while "scrolling" (paging) over to your other component.

See [React Native ScrollView Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) for information on how to implement this. There are likely other solutions, but this is the approach i would take.